# In name == 'main', why is variables shared in class?

Tags: python-3.x

Well, I just noticed that variables in `if name == 'main':` are shared to the classes in the same file - why is this? I don't recall having this issue in python2...

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, b):
        self.b = b

    def func_a(self):
        return d

if __name__ == '__main__':
    classA = A(1)

    d = 2

    print(classA.func_a())
```

prints out 2.

What's the reasoning?

Comment: Please include the before and after example and what you expect to happen. It's hard to understand the problem as is.

Comment: There is no before and after. I thought the if name==main would create a new namespace. It works as intended the code, and I also flagged the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this definitely also happens in python2
and is very simple: declaring variables outside of functions/classes makes them global and when python searches for variables with the name `d` it doesn't find it in the local scope but it does find the global variable

Comment: Ok, thought it would not happen inside the if __name__ == '__main__', as I am aware it happens if I declare it outside. Well just me being absent-minded :-)

Comment: it's understandable really, people use if name == main like a function so you might think it's a different scope but in python loops and ifs dont create their own scope

Comment: I was thinking of it as a function. But, of course, it's an if. Thanks for that little eureka moment.